# How do I do a reveal against a black background?

Tags: javascript, html, graphics

I have an HTML5-based game where I want to reveal the player's character in a certain way.

The end of the James Bond gun barrel sequence is sort of what I'm talking about: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YNajzHjjYXQ Around 0:17, there is a circle that reveals the next scene surrounded by a black background. Over the next few seconds, the circle expands to cover the whole screen and then all the black is gone. How can I do this in HTML5 and Javascript?

Answer (score 3):

I would probably do it with canvas and clip a circle before filling. Check the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NgCVA/

As a demonstration, I've placed an image (your game character) on the page and then absolutely positioned a canvas element above it:

```
<img src="http://zef.me/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/funny-dog-costume.jpg"/>
<canvas width="330" height="396"></canvas>​
```

Then you'll fill that entire canvas with black repeatedly in an animation loop while clipping a larger and larger circle:

```
var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0],
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),

    cx = canvas.width / 2, 
    cy = canvas.height / 2, 
    r = 10, 

    R_MAX = 400;

ctx.fillstyle = '#000';

function draw() {
    r += 1;

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);    

    ctx.save();
        // Draw clipping area
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
        ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, 0);
        ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.lineTo(0, canvas.height);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.moveTo(cx + r, cy);
        ctx.arc(cx, cy, r, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.clip();

        // Fill everything not clipped
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.restore();

    if(r < R_MAX) setTimeout(draw, 10);
}

draw();
```

Keep in mind that this is very simplistic animation and you'll probably want to do something more elegant (e.g. your own animation loop, easing, whatever).  The important part is the technique for clipping and filling on the canvas.

Comment: This is really awesome, thanks! I have a few questions though. | 1. I intend to use this effect to reveal the position of the player's avatar, and then the surroundings. So, I want this to originate at the player's coordinates of (hermes.currentX,hermes.currentY). How can I do that? | 2. The reveal appears to draw a white background or blank canvas. I want to keep my game map as the reveal happens. How can I do this?

Comment: 3. How would I do this in reverse? Assume that I have my game world being drawn and the game ends. The black should come in from the corners and the circle will grow smaller until there's nothing but black.

Comment: 1) 'cx', 'cy' are the coordinates of the center of the circle. Use any values you want. 2) Use multiple canvases. The map on one, sprites on another, the spotlight thing on another. Putting related items that are redrawn together onto a common canvas reduces the amount of things that need to be drawn in each frame (e.g. no need to redraw the map if it didn't move, just redraw the sprites).  3) 'r' is the current radius of the circle. Notice it stars at 10 and I keep adding one to it. Try starting at 400 and subtracting instead.